# How to get the values from 2 tables together in SQL

Tags: sql, union

I have 2 tables

```
1. emp_mst
empcode empname
001     abc
002     def

2. leavetotal
empcode leave 
001     10
001     5
001     2
002     12
002     8
```

Now i am trying to get the empcode and empname from the emp_mst
and the total for leave days from leavetotal.I have no idea how to get it. 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JOIN` / `GROUP BY` solution:

```
select e.empcode, e.empname, SUM(l.leave)
from emp_mst e
  left join leavetotal l on e.empcode = l.empcode
group by e.empcode, e.empname
```

`LEFT JOIN` to list even those without any leave. (Do just `JOIN` if not needed.)

Correlated sub-select solution:

```
select e.empcode, e.empname,
       (select SUM(l.leave) from leavetotal l
        where e.empcode = l.empcode)
from emp_mst e
```

Comment: Thanks jarlh. Your solution with sub-select worked perfectly fine. i will try out the method using join.

Answer (score 1):

In the FROM clause you can specify multiple tables, this will result in a cartesian product of the two tables. So each row in the a table will be joined with every other row in all other tables. This is of course not what you want, you only want rows with the same empcode to be joined. So that needs to be specified in the WHERE CLAUSE.

```
SELECT 
       MST.EMPCODE, 
       MST.EMPNAME, 
       SUM(LTO.LEAVE) 
FROM 
       EMP_MST MST, 
       LEAVETOTAL LTO 
WHERE 
       MST.EMPCODE = LTO.EMPCODE 
GROUP BY 
         EMPCODE, 
         EMPNAME
```

Comment: Please format your code so it's more readable. Also, old style join's are not ANSI SQL since '92; please use `JOIN` and `ON` keywords.

Comment: There is nothing "old" about that syntax.

Comment: @HoneyBadger, old style joins are actually ANSI SQL, even SQL-2011! (But I agree, don't use them...)

Comment: @jarlh, @Juru, Okay, I was repeating what I thought was right, might have my facts muddled. Still, I think most best practices advice `join` and `on` contruction.

Comment: I would advise to use it as much as possible. JOIN makes you think that there is something special to it, but it is just filtering like all other statements in the WHERE clause. I only use it when an OUTER join is required, which is something special.

Comment: In this case I'd say do explicit JOIN, because it is simple to convert to LEFT JOIN! (Which may actually be the preferred answer...)

Comment: hehe +1 for being a smartass @jarlh =)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a join, and then a group by:

```
SELECT   em.empcode, empname, SUM(leave)
FROM     emp_mst em
JOIN     leavetotal l ON em.empcode = l.empcode
GROUP BY em.empcode, empname
```